# Setting up Postfix for 2 domains on virtualhost

Tags: postfix, virtualhost

I've explored the Postfix documentation and it seems that that what I want to do is setup:
Postfix on a Null Client

Slicehost is a dead end for technical help, but here is what I want to do.

I need have email setup just to send out registration confirmations and new password requests.

I want to do this for 2 domains hosted on the server:
domain1.com
domain2.com

This is the current configuration for domain1.com:

## /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = mail.domain1.com   
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
myorigin = /etc/mailname  
mydestination = mail.domain1.com, instantdm, localhost.localdomain, localhost  
relayhost = domain1.com  
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128  
mailbox_size_limit = 0  
recipient_delimiter = +  
inet_interfaces = loopback only  
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
```

This is how it seems it seems main.cf should be configured for domain2.com, but I don't understand how to configure postfix for 2 different domain names.

## /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
 myorigin = domain2.com # this defines what the From address in the email user@domain.com vs. user@nullclient.example.com  
 relayhost = $mydomain  
 inet_interfaces = loopback-only  
 local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
```

Can you point me to better instructions or tell me how to configure this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should list domain1.com, domain2.com in "mydestination =", not "myorigin =".